# Efficient way of generating Multiple HTML Boxes

Tags: html, css

To generate html boxes one can simply:

html:

```
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
<div>Box 4</div>
<div>Box 5</div>
<div>Box 6</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In my project I need to create N number of boxes, is there a way of attach it without going through and create each one individually?

Comment: Not with pure HTML / CSS. You can do it with Javascript, or with some server-side language like PHP, if you are using that. Note that Javascript may not work on all browsers though.

Comment: I can use `php`, can i just use `echo` to generate multiple boxes using html?

Comment: @user1234440 Yep! Just make a loop, and echo them.

Comment: You can Use `$.each` function in jquery if you want to.

Comment: something like this, just echo divs instead of their examples: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: The comments aren't for answering the question, and that's exactly what happened here.  Stop posting answers in the comments, if you think it's an answer then provide it as a possible answer.

Comment: You are right @Fernker, I just commented to find out which techniques they could actually use. I will post the PHP-flavor of the answer.

Comment: i would be great if the answer is in php, because thats the method I am currently researching on how to do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with pure HTML / CSS. You can do it with PHP using a simple for-loop, e.g.

```
<?php
  for($i = 1; $i <= 6; ++$i)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"box\">Box $i</div>\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++){
   echo '<div id="'.$i.'">Box '.$i.'</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting: unexpected T_FOR error. Any idea what that means? I've added $x = 6 to ensure it will iterate 6 times to create 6 boxes.

Comment: I need to see the full code and the line it is giving the error. And possibly any other php code interacting with it